# Exception from SqlConnectionBuilder

Tags: c#, connection-string

A connection string is passed to a .net app from Delphi and this code throws an exception:

```
string conString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=tstuser;password=sa123&<>\"';Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Data Source=localhost;OLE DB Services=-4";

var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    ConnectionString = conString
};
```

When I split connection string and assign all properties - all good with builder:

```
Dictionary<string, string> conProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

connectionString.Split(';')
            .Select(t => t.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2))
            .ToDictionary(t => t[0].Trim(), t => t[1].Trim(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t => conProperties.Add(t.Key, t.Value));

var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    UserID = conProperties["User ID"],
    Password = conProperties["Password"],
    InitialCatalog = conProperties["Initial Catalog"],
    DataSource = conProperties["Data Source"]
};
```

Is there a bug in `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example does indeed yield an exception that indicates the problem:

`Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 36.`

The substring index corresponds to the password field. Some code demonstrates the issue here:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Password = "sa123&<>\\\"'";
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

This yields: `Password="sa123&<>\""'"` -- which suggests the problem is the connection string itself rather than the SqlConnectionStringBuilder; the " character in your input string needs to be doubled, and the whole password wrapped in quotes.

You don't hit this when setting the password via the property because the builder handles properly escaping the supplied string for you.

EDIT: The reason for having to do this is explained by the connection string syntax. The `\"` you've used in the question escapes the `"` character for the *compiler*, so it doesn't treat the `"` as terminating the string literal. However, the actual problem is the `'` that follows immediately afterwards; the syntax of the connection string has different rules around how quote characters are handled:

> The basic format of a connection string includes a series of
>   keyword/value pairs separated by semicolons. The equal sign (=)
>   connects each keyword and its value. To include values that contain a
>   semicolon, single-quote character, or double-quote character, the
>   value must be enclosed in double quotation marks. If the value
>   contains both a semicolon and a double-quote character, the value can
>   be enclosed in single quotation marks. The single quotation mark is
>   also useful if the value starts with a double-quote character.
>   Conversely, the double quotation mark can be used if the value starts
>   with a single quotation mark. If the value contains both single-quote
>   and double-quote characters, the quotation mark character used to
>   enclose the value must be doubled every time it occurs within the
>   value.
>
> To include preceding or trailing spaces in the string value, the value
>   must be enclosed in either single quotation marks or double quotation
>   marks. Any leading or trailing spaces around integer, Boolean, or
>   enumerated values are ignored, even if enclosed in quotation marks.
>   However, spaces within a string literal keyword or value are
>   preserved. Single or double quotation marks may be used within a
>   connection string without using delimiters (for example, Data Source=
>   my'Server or Data Source= my"Server), unless a quotation mark
>   character is the first or last character in the value.

(Source: [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks))

Since your connection string ends with a `'`, it is subject to the wrapping rule in the last sentence.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I still don't get it - why do we need doubled " - it's already escaped as \"